# How to recover my source code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

after a system crash down, one of my .cs file get lost. 
The size of the file is 18KB, 
when I tried to open it in VS2010, vs2010 auto opens it in NotePad, but the content is empty.
I tried to open it in NotePad++, the content turns into bunches of black block with word "NULL" in it.
I tried to "save as" in UTF8, but the file is empty as same.

How to recover this lost .cs file? :(

Comment: Have you run a `CHKDSK /F` on the drive (will require a reboot if your data is on the system drive)? If that doesn't help, then the data is probably lost - you're using a VCS, are you? ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622901/recover-a-cs-class-file-after-crash

Comment: do you have your program exe file?.NET Reflector v6  provides support for .NET Framework 4.0 assemblies. Download it

Comment: @Usher great idea with Reflector. But it is payment tool now so I recommend to use ILSpy - http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx

Comment: Visual Studio does retain *some* autorecover information. It's usually in `C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Backup Files`.

Comment: - Now that **.NET Reflector** is a paid tool, there are many, many free versions that people have created, such as **ILSpy**, or **dotPeek** from **JetBrains**

Though, if you are **REALLY** committed to this `.cs` file, then I'd just purchase **.NET Reflector**, because it has **very**, **very** good results. -**BUT**, that's just __my__ opinion :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use any recovery tool (isn't important that it is cs file).

and you have to use external subversion control next time.

I've been using [xp-dev.com](http://xp-dev.com/). It has free plan. Try to google and you will find out more services like this.

**EDIT:** There mentioned about code decompile - it is good idea. Try to use [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) - open source tool.

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever compile it so you have a .dll/.exe file with the compiled class in it? If so, then you can use a decompiler such as [dotPeek from JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/), or Reflector from RedGate to decompile the file and get the .cs code back.

You will be suprised how well preserved the source code is. Sometimes I find that the compiled->decompiled code is better looking than the code was before compilation...

Remember to use version control and backups, it does seem like there is something wrong with your disk.

Comment: Code compile/decompile as a Tidy operation, very nice

Answer (score 1):

I had *exactly* the same issue yesterday :)

Additionally my drive was encrypted, and when I opened the file with Notepad++ it was all filled with `NULL`s. The problem is, if your drive is encrypted, there is **no way to recover the data** (apart from reading IL code and converting it back to C# from the compiled library). But, thankfully, all I needed to do was to check out original version from git hub.

I hope you did use source control. If you didn't, well this would be a good lesson.

Comment: Why would anyone post something like this if they could just `svn revert` (or equivalent) and it'd restore the file?

Comment: @DanielBeck the easiest way not to get into such situations is to commit often. My suggestion was to fix the root problem, rather than to fix a single failure. If one cannot update code from the repository, it is a much bigger trouble (given this is production code).

Comment: @oleksii , hmm, I finally recover nearly 90% of my code by decompiling DLL file, and I learn my lesson, now I tried to SVN my project to a server, thanks...

Answer (score 1):

This is because the operation delete has happened on the file, and the code or data in your file is interrupted in the interim stage. It's not either committed to source safe or retained. Try getting older version and you have to write code again.

This happens sometimes even if your hard disk is not crashed

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few steps you can do

- try to recover the files "physically" via the free [Recuva tool](http://www.piriform.com/recuva).
- try to recover them from your temporary files folder in the user and files directory of windows
- Try to look inside the (Global) [Assembly Cache](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4352/Demystifying-the-NET-Global-Assembly-Cache) and disassemble back your application to C# via [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy)

Comment: Thanks for reminder about ILSpy, you literary saved my as :)

Answer (score 0):

do you have your program exe file?
.NET Reflector v6  provides support for .NET Framework 4.0 assemblies. Download it from [here](http://reflector.red-gate.com/download.aspx).